# How to make spring cloud stubrunner boot register stubs in Eureka Discovery?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to register my cloud contract stubs with a running Eureka discovery service for smoke-testing. The stubrunner itself is successfully registered in the service discovery, but the endpoints provided by the stubs are not reachable as expected.

The stubs should replace the real masterdata microservice (rest apis).

*Stubrunner main class:*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableStubRunnerServer
@EnableEurekaClient
@AutoConfigureStubRunner
class EurekaStubRunnerApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<EurekaStubRunnerApplication>(*args)
}
```

*Stubrunner bootstrap.yml*

```
spring:
  application:
    name: masterdata
jhipster:
  registry:
    password: admin
```

*Stubrunner application.yml*

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/
    enabled: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: false
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    instance-info-replication-interval-seconds: 10
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 10
  instance:
    appname: masterdata
    instance-id: masterdata:${spring.application.instance-id:${random.value}}
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 10
    status-page-url-path: management/info
    health-check-url-path: management/health
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true
server:
  port: 8888
stubrunner:
  cloud:
    eureka:
      enabled: true
    stubbed:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
```

*Command to start stub runner:*

```
java -jar eureka-stub-runner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --stubrunner.ids=com.xetics.mes:masterdata-stubs:+:8081 --stubrunner.stubsMode=LOCAL
```

When I start the real masterdata service, I can call the api endpoint via the running gateway:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTU0NjYxMDc2OH0.EF3PHho-B-ayOmmeFrcA90U38cd3AZsU7pA7-9xN0SpuVBvev2sHvejv-FI_FlrwP7qWcCpibW-yWwFDBSUv9w' 'http://localhost:8080/masterdata/api/stations'
[]
```

The same call with stubs running in the stub runner:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTU0NjYxMDc2OH0.EF3PHho-B-ayOmmeFrcA90U38cd3AZsU7pA7-9xN0SpuVBvev2sHvejv-FI_FlrwP7qWcCpibW-yWwFDBSUv9w' 'http://localhost:8080/masterdata/api/stations'
{"timestamp":"2019-01-03T16:59:36.426+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/stations"}
```

Although, I can call the stubs directly:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTU0NjYxMDc2OH0.EF3PHho-B-ayOmmeFrcA90U38cd3AZsU7pA7-9xN0SpuVBvev2sHvejv-FI_FlrwP7qWcCpibW-yWwFDBSUv9w' 'http://localhost:8081/api/stations'
[{"archiveTime":null,"description":"A fantastic base for building a time machine","id":1985,"maxCapacity":2,"name":"DeLorean DMC 12","icon":"delorean-icon"},{"archiveTime":null,"description":"A handy tool for manipulating the space time continuum","id":2015,"maxCapacity":1,"name":"Flux capacitor"}]
```

What am I doing wrong? As far as I understood that issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/pull/64 , it should be possible to register the stubs in the Eureka server, nor?

I've also read the following documentations without any success:

- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.x/#_additional_configuration
- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/master/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were caused by the following misconfiguration of the application.

```
...
stubrunner:
  cloud:
    eureka:
      enabled: true
    stubbed:
      discovery:
        # must be false instead of
        enabled: true
```

In addition, I needed to add a service mapping as my stubs artifact id is *masterdata-stubs* whereas the service id to call is *masterdata*.

The working application.yml looks like this now:

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/
    enabled: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: false
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    instance-info-replication-interval-seconds: 10
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 10
  instance:
    appname: stubrunner
    instance-id: stubrunner:${spring.application.instance-id:${random.value}}
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 10
    status-page-url-path: management/info
    health-check-url-path: management/health
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true
server:
  port: 8888
stubrunner:
  cloud:
    eureka:
      enabled: true
    stubbed:
      discovery:
        enabled: false
  idsToServiceIds:
    masterdata-stubs: masterdata
```